# Relinquish control in JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have a JFrame that creates a modeless JDialog.  Under certain situations (maybe always) that I pass to the JDialog constructor, I would like the JDialog to remain visible but have control return to the calling JFrame.  The user may subsequently interact with, or close, the JDialog.

I've researched, but have not found a way to do this.  Any suggestions/help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried simply calling `frame.toFront()` after showing the dialog?

For example,

```
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class RelinquishControl {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextField textField = new JTextField("Fubar", 15);
      textField.selectAll();
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(textField);
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      textField = new JTextField("Fubar", 15);
      textField.selectAll();
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(textField);
      final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", ModalityType.MODELESS);
      dialog.add(panel);
      dialog.pack();
      int x = frame.getLocation().x + 200;
      int y = frame.getLocation().y + 200;
      dialog.setLocation(x, y);
      dialog.setVisible(true);

      frame.toFront();
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 A simpler solution than my suggestion ( I learned something today). Not sure if the SSCCE was really required for a one line solution especially since the GUI is not created on the EDT.

Comment: `Dialog` overrides `toBack()` in a platform dependent way, making it a less appealing alternative; the SCCEE made it easy to check.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - frame.toFront(); - I love it!  Thanks.